# Extract line by line from csv python

Tags: python, csv

i have a csv file and i want to extract every single line and save it in different files.
For exemple i extract the line 1 and save it to line1.txt then the line 2 and save it to line2.txt ...
This is my code

```
with open('output.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
        csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
        for row in csv_dict_reader:
            print(row['DOC_TYPE'],row['EXTRACTED_TEXT'])
```

i tried to use this function but his is only for the first line

```
headers=next(file_data)
```

i tried to use this but it didn't work

```
print(row['EXTRACTED_TEXT'][0])
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: You don't need any CSV handling modules for this. Just open the file, read one line at a time and write that to a new file changing the output filename every time you get a line

Comment: Stuart thank you for you answer. What do you mean ? how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
with open('output.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    for fname, line in enumerate(read_obj):
        with open(f"line{fname}.txt") as write_obj:
            write_obj.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line DictReader(read_obj)

I think it should be csv.DictReader(read_obj) .
Also depending on your experience are you using "import csv" at the start?

Edit on comment:

```
A=[]
for row in csv_dict_reader:
    A.append(row)
#now rows are elements of this list. 
#For printing 3rd line 
print(A[2])
```

Comment: It is the same. I mean csv.DictReader(read_obj) and DictReader(read_obj) give me the same result. and i can read and extract all texts correctly but the problem is how can i extract lines that i want to extract. For exemple i want just to extract line 3

Comment: @Atef       (l0) A=[] (l1)  for row in csv_dict_reader: (l2) A.append(row) (l3) print(A[2])

Comment: Once you make a new array A you can access specific line as an array using A[]. and elements using A[][]